# Get JMSXDeliveryCount within Camel Route

Tags: java, apache-camel, rollback

I have a routeContext in which I am trying to determine the following. If the JMSXDeliveryCount (a message property) is  less than 5, I want to rollback. If it is greater than 5, I want to log a message and leave.

The following below is my routeContext:

```
<routeContext id="inbound-errorhandler-route" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route id="errorhandler">
       <from uri="direct:inboundErrorHandler" id="errorHandlerDirect"/>
       <choice>
           <when>
               <simple>${exchangeProperty.JMSXDeliveryCount} >= 5</simple>
               <log message="Message retry attempts exhausted, retry count: {{exchangeProperty.JMSXDeliveryCount}}. Not rolling back: ${body}" loggingLevel="ERROR" logName="CamelContext-Route"/>
           </when>
           <otherwise>
               <log message="Caught Unknown Exception - Camel Context route processing - failed : ${body}"
                    loggingLevel="ERROR" logName="CamelContext-Route"/>
               <rollback message="The current message was marked for Rollback, retry count: {{exchangeProperty.JMSXDeliveryCount}}. Please see redelivery policy for re-attempts."/>
           </otherwise>
       </choice>
   </route> 
</routeContext>
```

However, I am never entering the first choice, and in my log message for the rollback, the deliveryCount is not getting updated. It is just showing as the plain text `{exchangeProperty.JMSXDeliveryCount}`.

How do I properly get a message property, in particular the JMSXDeliveryCount, and how do I make a decision on that property?

I am using Camel 2.15.2

Answer (score 2):

To fix the issue I was having with the plain text, I had to use a dollar sign and brackets to reference the object within the simple brackets:

`<simple>${header.JMSXDeliveryCount} >= 5 </simple>`

I also needed to use the header object, not the exchangeProperty to reference the JMS delivery count.

```
<routeContext id="inbound-errorhandler-route" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route id="errorhandler">
       <from uri="direct:inboundErrorHandler" id="errorHandlerDirect"/>
       <choice>
           <when>
               <simple>${header.JMSXDeliveryCount} >= 5</simple>
               <log message="Message retry attempts exhausted, retry count: ${header.JMSXDeliveryCount}. Not rolling back. Message body: ${body}" loggingLevel="ERROR" logName="CamelContext-Route"/>
           </when>
           <otherwise>
               <log message="Caught Unknown Exception - Camel Context route processing - failed, retry count: ${header.JMSXDeliveryCount}. Rolling back. Message body: ${body}"
                    loggingLevel="ERROR" logName="CamelContext-Route"/>
               <rollback message="The current message was marked for Rollback. Please see redelivery policy for re-attempts."/>
           </otherwise>
       </choice>
   </route> 
</routeContext>
```